# Is it a good idea to store code in database?

Tags: language-agnostic

I'm writing a game for social network and we have a lot of formulas for weapons stats, items stats etc that depend on player's characteristics. Formulas look like
`player.money += 10 * player.level`

It looks like a good idea to just store functions like these in db and let game-designer enter them through admin site.

But i'm not sure about this. What problems can occur with this approach?

Thank you.

Comment: That's not code you are talking about.

Comment: No, i really mean code. like "player.money += 10 * player.level"

Comment: You wouldn't really store that as code. For one, that's highly insecure. You would probably use fields in the database with fields like `MoneyToAdd` which is the base amount and `MoneyModifier` for an enum value that would signify to multiply that by the players level. You could also only use the `MoneyToAdd` field and have the modifier logic in your game.

Answer (score 2):

The issue you need to contend with is not whether you should use a database (you should) but the proper design of such. Consider the object hierarchy you have in the game and how that would be reflected in a database.

Making a database column for each property is a bad idea in that it is too rigid. You want to look at a "property bag" approach where you have look-up tables for most of it that can be indexed for performance.

This of a model like this:

**itemId, propertyId, propertyValue**

For higher performance, combine this with something like [Memcached.](http://memcached.org/)

Answer (score 1):

This would be an OK approach. As Jon pointed out, it's not really "code", more like item/equipment attributes.

**Pros**

- Easy to modify

**Cons**

- Requires a lookup for each item or piece of equipment

The fact that you will be doing a lookup for each item could be a performance bottleneck. If you decide to use a DB in the end, I would suggest pulling data from it once and then caching it for, say, the rest of the session. The item attributes aren't likely to change frequently, and this will limit the queries to the database.